# lua repeat/until seems to use original value

Tags: lua

So still working on a program that converts digits to Chinese pinyin. Full code (please excuse the wonkyness, and I do really appreciate all the help with my bad coding)

```
local digitmap = {
   ["0"] = "ying2",
   ["1"] = "yi1",
   ["2"] = "er2",
   ["3"] = "san1",
   ["4"] = "si4",
   ["5"] = "wu3",
   ["6"] = "liu4",
   ["7"] = "qi1",
   ["8"] = "ba1",
   ["9"] = "jiu3",
}

print("Enter a number to be converted (up to 10 digits long):")

while true do
    number = tonumber(io.read("*line"))
    nlength = #(tostring(number))
    if number ~= nil and nlength <= 10 then
        break
    end
    print("Invalid input or too long. Please try again:")
end

if number == 0 then
fconvnumber = "ying2"
zero = true
end

local cwords = {}
for c in string.gmatch(number, "%d") do
cwords[#cwords + 1] = digitmap[c]
end

if nlength == 2 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
elseif nlength == 3 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
elseif nlength == 4 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
elseif nlength == 5 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
elseif nlength == 6 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
elseif nlength == 7 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 6] = cwords[nlength - 6] .. " bai3 "
elseif nlength == 8 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 6] = cwords[nlength - 6] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 7] = cwords[nlength - 7] .. " qian1 "
elseif nlength == 9 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 6] = cwords[nlength - 6] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 7] = cwords[nlength - 7] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 8] = cwords[nlength - 8] .. " yi4 "
elseif nlength == 10 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 6] = cwords[nlength - 6] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 7] = cwords[nlength - 7] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 8] = cwords[nlength - 8] .. " yi4 "
    cwords[nlength - 9] = cwords[nlength - 9] .. " shi2 "
end

while cwords[nlength] == "ying2" and zero ~= true do
    cwords[nlength] = nil
    nlength = nlength - 1
end

fconvnumber = table.concat(cwords)

fconvnumber = string.gsub(fconvnumber, "ying2 %a+%d", "ying2")
for i=1,nlength do
    fconvnumber = string.gsub(fconvnumber, "ying2 ying2", "ying2")
end
fconvnumber = string.gsub(fconvnumber, "yi1 shi2", "shi2")

print(fconvnumber)
```

So, for instance, if I put in 100, nlength is 3, cwords[nlength] == "ying2", and it deletes the last array. But it doesn't cycle through again and delete the tens place 0. I know I must be missing the logic somehow, but I just don't see it. Does until use the earlier valua of nlength? Thank you!

Comment: Lua would only be failing if immediately after this line, `cwords[nlength] == "ying2"` was true. And it's not. So odds are good, it's your `cwords` array that doesn't contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: see at the end, I help you solve your actual problem...

A few things about your updated code:

**1) You are using gmatch on a number, not a string.**

It only works because of coercion, which is not a good idea. You can make sure by using the OO-style call instead:

```
for c in number:gmatch("%d") do
```

It will break with this error:

```
attempt to index global 'number' (a number value)
```

You should keep a string version of the number, like this:

```
while true do
    number = tonumber(io.read("*line"))
    str_number = tostring(number)
    nlength = #str_number
    if number ~= nil and nlength <= 10 then
        break
    end
    print("Invalid input or too long. Please try again:")
end

if number == 0 then
    fconvnumber = "ying2"
    zero = true
end

local cwords = {}
for c in str_number:gmatch("%d") do
    cwords[#cwords + 1] = digitmap[c]
end
```

**2) This part is horribly repetitive:**

```
if nlength == 2 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
elseif nlength == 3 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
elseif nlength == 4 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
elseif nlength == 5 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
elseif nlength == 6 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
elseif nlength == 7 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 6] = cwords[nlength - 6] .. " bai3 "
elseif nlength == 8 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 6] = cwords[nlength - 6] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 7] = cwords[nlength - 7] .. " qian1 "
elseif nlength == 9 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 6] = cwords[nlength - 6] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 7] = cwords[nlength - 7] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 8] = cwords[nlength - 8] .. " yi4 "
elseif nlength == 10 then
    cwords[nlength - 1] = cwords[nlength - 1] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 2] = cwords[nlength - 2] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 3] = cwords[nlength - 3] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 4] = cwords[nlength - 4] .. " wan2 "
    cwords[nlength - 5] = cwords[nlength - 5] .. " shi2 "
    cwords[nlength - 6] = cwords[nlength - 6] .. " bai3 "
    cwords[nlength - 7] = cwords[nlength - 7] .. " qian1 "
    cwords[nlength - 8] = cwords[nlength - 8] .. " yi4 "
    cwords[nlength - 9] = cwords[nlength - 9] .. " shi2 "
end
```

You can replace the whole block by:

```
local suffixes = {"shi2","bai3","qian1","wan2","shi2","bai3","qian1","yi4","shi2"}
for i=1,nlength-1 do
    cwords[nlength - i] = string.format("%s %s ", cwords[nlength - i], suffixes[i])
end
```

**3) This is useless:**

```
if number == 0 then
    fconvnumber = "ying2"
    zero = true
end
```

You set fconvnumber but you will re-set it later anyway on this line:

```
fconvnumber = table.concat(cwords)
```

Testing for zero is used only once later in the while loop:

```
while cwords[nlength] == "ying2" and zero ~= true do
    cwords[nlength] = nil
    nlength = nlength - 1
end
```

Moreover you are repeating the test at every iteration. You could just remove the first block and write:

```
if number ~= 0 then
    while cwords[nlength] == "ying2" do
        cwords[nlength] = nil
        nlength = nlength - 1
    end
end
```

Eventually your refactored code looks like this:

```
local digitmap = {
    ["0"] = "ying2",
    ["1"] = "yi1",
    ["2"] = "er2",
    ["3"] = "san1",
    ["4"] = "si4",
    ["5"] = "wu3",
    ["6"] = "liu4",
    ["7"] = "qi1",
    ["8"] = "ba1",
    ["9"] = "jiu3",
}

print("Enter a number to be converted (up to 10 digits long):")

while true do
    number = tonumber(io.read("*line"))
    str_number = tostring(number)
    nlength = #str_number
    if number ~= nil and nlength <= 10 then
        break
    end
    print("Invalid input or too long. Please try again:")
end

local cwords = {}
for c in str_number:gmatch("%d") do
    cwords[#cwords + 1] = digitmap[c]
end

local suffixes = {"shi2","bai3","qian1","wan2","shi2","bai3","qian1","yi4","shi2"}
for i=1,nlength-1 do
    cwords[nlength - i] = string.format("%s %s ", cwords[nlength - i], suffixes[i])
end

if number ~= 0 then
    while cwords[nlength] == "ying2" do
        cwords[nlength] = nil
        nlength = nlength - 1
    end
end

fconvnumber = table.concat(cwords)

fconvnumber = string.gsub(fconvnumber, "ying2 %a+%d", "ying2")
for i=1,nlength do
    fconvnumber = string.gsub(fconvnumber, "ying2 ying2", "ying2")
end
fconvnumber = string.gsub(fconvnumber, "yi1 shi2", "shi2")

print(fconvnumber)
```

There are probably still things that can be improved but this is already simpler :)

**So now let's solve the real problem!**

You say:

> So, for instance, if I put in 100, nlength is 3, cwords[nlength] ==
>   "ying2", and it deletes the last array. But it doesn't cycle through
>   again and delete the tens place 0. I know I must be missing the logic
>   somehow, but I just don't see it.

That is because the last element of the array after the first iteration is not "ying2", it is "ying2 shi2 "! Think about it, you have concatenated " shi2 " earlier.

Now the question is: is the result you are expecting "yi1 bai3" or "yi1"?

If it is "yi1" just eliminate the zeroes before concatenating. If it is "yi1 bai3" do something like this:

```
local suffixes = {"shi2","bai3","qian1","wan2","shi2","bai3","qian1","yi4","shi2"}
cwords[nlength] = {cwords[nlength]}
for i=1,nlength-1 do
    cwords[nlength - i] = {cwords[nlength - i],string.format(" %s ",suffixes[i])}
end

if number ~= 0 then
    while cwords[nlength][1] == "ying2" do
        cwords[nlength] = nil
        nlength = nlength - 1
    end
end

for i=1,nlength do
    cwords[i] = table.concat(cwords[i])
end

fconvnumber = table.concat(cwords)
```

Comment: Finally figured it out last night... thanks for all the help with the horrid repetitiveness!

Answer (score 2):

As you don't provide your complete code, it's difficult to say, but I suspect you don't populate `cwords` correctly as I don't see an issue in the code you posted. This works for me:

```
cwords = {1, "ying2", "ying2"}
nlength = #cwords
print("started with", #cwords)
repeat
if cwords[nlength] == "ying2" then
    cwords[nlength] = nil
    nlength = nlength - 1
end
until cwords[nlength] ~= "ying2"
print("ended with", #cwords)
```

You may want to change this to be `while` loop instead as the logic is simpler:

```
while nlength > 0 and cwords[nlength] == "ying2" do
    cwords[nlength] = nil
    nlength = nlength - 1
end
```

Comment: Complete code it up there now. I was a bit afraid it'd be too long. tx!

Comment: I still don't see the problem as even your original code works. I'd follow Mud's suggestion and remove zeroes before conversion...

Comment: Well at least I know I wasn't missing something really obvious! On it. tx!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with logic. Either `cwords` or `nlength` are not initialized properly.

The code is a bit wonky, though. You're doing the same test twice per loop, which should be [a red flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

You can do the same thing like this:

```
while cwords[nlength] == "ying2" do
    cwords[nlength] = nil
    nlength = nlength - 1
end
```

Or like this:

```
while cwords[#cwords] == "ying2" do
    table.remove(cwords)
end
```

But the most efficient way would be to strip trailing zeros from the source number *before* doing the conversion to pinyin:

```
while number % 10 == 0 do
    number = number / 10
end
```

Or:

```
strnumber = strnumber:match('(.-)0*$')
```

Comment: Thanks for listing all those options, since this is a learning experience for me, it really helps!